# Cost increase and suspend

Tags: magic-the-gathering

During a recent game, my opponent Suspended two [Rift Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRift%20Bolt%5d) in the same turn. Then, during my turn, I played a [Damping Sphere](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDamping%20Sphere%5d).

The way we resolved it, is that at the next turn, my opponent payed `1` for the second Rift Bolt.
I'm not sure if this is correct, because the rule text for supspend says that when you remove the last suspend counter you cast the spell *without* paying its mana cost. 
So, to me, it sounds like even if the cost was increased, one still does not need to pay for it.

What's the correct thing to do?
If actually one needs to pay for the second suspended spell, what would happen if he can't?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I didn't know about the [mtg:] link trick :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first Rift Bolt costs {0} to cast, and the second costs {1}.

---

The total cost to cast a spell
= mana cost or alternative cost
+ additional costs and cost increases
- cost reductions

Suspend allows spells to be cast for the alternative cost of "free". Cost increases, such as the one from Damping Sphere, still apply.<sup>[1]</sup>

If you can't cast it (because you can't or choose not to produce the mana for it), it will remain exiled indefinitely.

---

1. Only [Trinisphere](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTrinisphere%5d) modifies the total cost.

Comment: Ok, thanks... so if one cannot pay for the second rift bolt, it would just fizzle?

Comment: "Fizzle" usually means "countered (by the rules) for not having any valid targets". That's not the case here. Note that Suspend says "When the last time counter is removed from this card, if it’s exiled, play it without paying its mana cost **if able**." The Riftbolt wouldn't even be cast, and it would be permanently stuck in exile (unless you have a way of adding time counters to an exiled card, or unless you use something like a Ring of Three Wishes).

Comment: Ah, yes, I've found the relevant section of the rules: 702.61a -> If you can’t, it remains exiled.

Comment: @ikegami The casual definition of “fizzle” is changed now; because it would no longer be countered.

Answer (score 0):

## You still have to pay the taxman. (If you want your spells cast)

When a card comes of suspend you cast it without paying its mana cost, but any additional costs, like these 'tax' cost, still need to be paid if you want to cast your spells.

If the mana is in your mana pool then you must pay these additional costs, you can choose to not tap your mana which makes the paying of the tax impossible. If you choose not to pay the tax the spell will remain in exile with no way to be cast.

Comment: that is news to me, where is that rule from?

Comment: ok, will edit..